# Waiting for staking

Tags: staking

I've received this error :
`billed CPU time (1277 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (0 us)`. I guess I need to stake EOS for CPU. If I stake for example, 3.0 EOS for an account, do I need to wait 72 hours to be able to complete new transactions? I just staked 3 EOS but my bandwidth was decreased from 18.95 msec to 6.8 msec.

There is how I stake:
`cleos -u https://eos.greymass.com:443 system delegatebw myacount otheraccount "0.0 EOS" "1.0 EOS"`

Answer (score 1):

The wait time for CPU and BET bandwidth to reset is 24 hours, not 72 hours.

You have to stake EOS to your account in order to use it. CPU allows you to perform actions and NET is for transferring of data over the network.

The bandwidth you have at any moment fluctuates, as although you are guaranteed a fixed amount of CPU time for a given amount of staked EOS, you can have *more* than that if the network is under utilised. However in the moment when the network suddenly gets very busy, your CPU allowance can drop significantly.